# Insert query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, insert

Need your help optimising an insert query.

I have two tables in my MySQL DB. I will be inserting into Table1. Information will be retreived in Table2.

Table 2 contains a couple of million records. 
My insert query should look for all users who has a previous event in Table2 and insert it into Table1.

This is my insert query - but it's killing my server.

```
INSERT INTO Table1(
SELECT   
    d.created,
    d.userID, 
    d.eventID,
    d.previousEvent
FROM (
SELECT    
    e.created,
    e.userID,
    e.eventID,
    (SELECT eventID FROM TABLE2 pe WHERE e.userID=pe.userID AND e.created>pe.created ORDER BY pe.created DESC LIMIT 1) AS e.previousEvent
FROM 
    TABLE2 e
WHERE
    e.eventID not in (Select f.EventID from TABLE1 f)
ORDER BY 
    e.created desc
) d
WHERE
    d.preEvent is not null
GROUP by
    d.eventID,
    d.created,
    d.userID
);
```

eg:

Table1:

```
created     |   userID    |   eventID(unique)   |   previousEvent
2015-11-15      66666          1045698664           4566660001
```

Table2:

```
created     |   userID    |   eventID(unique - random)
2015-11-15      55555          4755500001
2015-11-15      66666          4566660001
2015-11-15      77777          8634757777
2015-11-15      88888          1845562565
2015-11-15      66666          1045698664
```

Comment: On your tables/columns have you tried creating an index? If so what is the fragmentation level of the index(s)

Answer (score 0):

> not in (Select f.EventID from TABLE1 f)

optimizes poorly.  Turn it into a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
LEFT JOIN TABLE1  ON e.EventID = f.EventID
WHERE f.EventID IS NULL
```